# Google App Engine: Which is its RDBMS?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, cloud, azure

According to this: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html
it seems that GAE only uses Datastore to store data, which is equivalent with Table service on Windows Azure Platform.

Does anyone know that which RDBMS it uses? or such thing exists or not?

EDIT: Windows Azure Platform, a cloud-computing platform by Microsoft, offers 2 options to store data:

- Windows Azure Storage service, which include Table service, which is similar with GAE Datastore. Both store data in entities, and their "tables" are schemeless
- SQL Azure, which is a RDBMS on the cloud, based on SQL Server. It supports most features of SQL Server, includes T-SQL

That's why I think it's hard to believe that Google App Engine doesn't offer a RDBMS. I searched, but found no confirmation. That's why I asked here

Comment: Why do someone need to close this question???

Comment: I voted to close the question.  There is no offense intended.  This strikes me as the kind of question you could answer on your own via search engine.  Of course others may disagree, including yourself.  It generally takes 5 votes to close a question, so don't worry too much :-)

Comment: The very page you linked to in the question says "The App Engine datastore is not like a traditional relational database".  I'm not sure what more can be said.

Comment: @Adam Bernier: I searched but found no confirmation about this. That's why I need to ask this question
@Ken: Windows Azure Table service is similar with DataStore, but Microsoft offers SQL Azure as a RDBMS on the cloud. That's what I can say

Answer (score 14, accepted):

App Engine doesn't use an RDBMS, though we did just announce that we'll be supporting SQL in the near future in [App Engine for Business](http://code.google.com/appengine/business/). The App Engine datastore is based on [Bigtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable).

Answer (score 4):

It is not a RDBMS in the usual sense of that word.  In a relational database, data is stored in relations (commonly called tables) base on candidate keys.  Every relation has a primary key, for a database to be normalized, all other data in a relation is related to the primary key, the whole key and nothing but the key.

From http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/:

> The App Engine datastore is a
>   schemaless object datastore, with a
>   query engine and atomic transactions.
>   The Python interface includes a rich
>   data modeling API and a SQL-like query
>   language called GQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure RDBMS applies to cloud computing!

Comment: SQL Azure is a RDBMS on the cloud, based on SQL Server